# How to insert null value to foreign key with JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2, jdbctemplate

I've the following schema :

```
CREATE TABLE API
(
ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
API_PARENT_ID BIGINT,
CONSTRAINT API_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (ID)
CONSTRAINT API_PARENT_ID_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (API_PARENT_ID) references API,
);
```

My API entity have a FK on itself in case of api dependencies (like child-parent relation)

I've handle myself (meaning I've avoided to use hibernate) the CRUD part with a jdbc template.
I've encountering a problem when my API is the parent and then the api_parent_id value should be null.

The following line (i've skipped the meaningless columns):

```
String _SQL_UPDATE_API = "update api set api_parent_id = ? where id = ?"
this.jdbcTemplate.update(_SQL_UPDATE_API, api.getParent !=null ? api.getParent().getId() : null , api.getId());
```

return the following error :

```
[90012-196]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement: update api set api_parent_id = ? where id = ?
```

How should I handle the null value ? 
I've tried with MapSqlParameterSource or with a PreparedStatement in specifying the

```
ps.setNull(1,Types.NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ps.setNull(1,Types.NULL);

Unfortunately, you'll need to set the specific JDBC type of the column that corresponds to the type of the column, according to your JDBC driver.

Some JDBC drivers are pickier than other ones. I guess H2 needs the specific type.

In this case, use `Types.BIGINT`, as in:

```
ps.setNull(1,Types.BIGINT);
```

Comment: I've already try this solution, but H2 convert the set null with a 0 value, which not corresponding to something in my table as it is a FK

Comment: Well, finally this worked, I had a problem with the extraction data of the entity, by default it was mapping a new ApiParent on my entity, then the it my update it was alway not null and sending 0..

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument along with arguments type using this [update](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-) function.

```
Integer id = 1
Integer parent_id = null

String _SQL_UPDATE_API = "update api set api_parent_id = ? where id = ?";

java.lang.Object[] args = [parent_id, id]
int[] argTypes   = [java.sql.Types.BIGINT, java.sql.Types.BIGINT]

updCnt = jdbcTemplate.update(_SQL_UPDATE_API, args, argTypes);
```

Note - this is Groovy syntax, so adjust for Java if required.

Worked for my in Oracle 12.

Comment: I've tried this solution also, but now i've this error : org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [ update api set api_parent_id = ? where id = ?]; Data conversion error converting "(-5, -5)"

Comment: Well, if everything fails, I'd use an *additional* statement for the `NULL`case:  `update api set api_parent_id = NULL where id = ?`

Comment: Well, this solution won't work because the parent_id won't be always null

Comment: You would use `if (parent_id != null) then` your original statement and only in `else` this modified one.